# Euclidean distance between multivariate series

Tags: time-series, distance-functions, euclidean

If A={(5,1),(2,3),(4,5)} and B={(4,3),(3,4),(2,3)} are two series, how is the euclidean distance between them calculated?

Would it be $\sqrt{(5-4)^2+(1-3)^2} + \sqrt{(2-3)^2+(3-4)^2} + \sqrt{(4-2)^2+(5-3)^2}$ ?

Comment: Are you looking to find the pairwise Euclidean distances? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_matrix

Comment: I am looking for distance between the two series A and B

Comment: I'd also be interested in knowing what distance means between two series. The way you suggest, order matters. But should it?

Comment: What exactly is the geometric interpretation of a series? Perhaps a cluster of points? And you're looking for the distance between two clusters.

Comment: More like time series. For example, (5,1) would be the position at time t1, (2,3) would be the position at time t2 and so on. So yes, order matters in such a case.

Comment: I see. So a non-parametric distance measure between two sets of ordered observations, for example.

Comment: Yes. Would specifically like to know if Euclidean distance can be applied to such cases.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184977/multivariate-time-series-euclidean-distance.